# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to display multiple username with their image So, I have a Json action method like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUsers()
{
     var ret = (from user in db.Users
                orderby user.UserName
                select new
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    Pic = GetFileData(user.Id),
                }).AsEnumerable();
     return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this is my `GetFileData` method to get user's image:

```
public FileResult GetFileData(int Id)
{
    var avatarImage = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationUserId == Id);
    return File(avatarImage.Content, avatarImage.ContentType);
}
```

Here, `ApplicationUserId` is the foreign key relating File and `ApplicationUser` class.

Now, when I run the query, I should get username with their pic But I am getting `System.NotSupportedException`.The complete error message is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult GetFileData(Int32)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

How to get it resolved.I have seen many stackoverflow question relating it but none of the question was relating to FileResult.The code for view page is here http://pastebin.com/AyrpGgEm

Comment: Well have you tried applying the same *reasoning* for the other questions to your situation? Basically, you almost certainly just need `AsEnumerable()` *before* the select, e.g. `db.Users.OrderBy(user => user.UserName).AsEnumerable().Select(user => new { user.UserName, Pic = GetFileData(user.Id) })`

Comment: You will at least to materialize your query before the `select` (e.g. `.ToList()`)

Comment: I have never tried to serialize `FileResult` to Json but I'm not surprised in won't work. I suspect you need to send the images in Base64 format

Comment: Aside from anything else, I wouldn't think you'd want to make that many individual fetches anyway. It would be better to do a join to get all the data in one query, then extract appropriate entities. But it's not clear what `avatarImage.Content` is anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet u can see both the classes here http://pastebin.com/kVTX71ZK

Comment: @duke: Given that they're relevant to the question, they should be *in* the question.

Comment: But we've moved past the problem in the question anyway - and we don't know what the stack trace for the new exception looks like. You should ask a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 3):

`GetFileData` couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. You can modify the code as below (Move the `GetFileData` out of expression):

```
var pic = GetFileData(user.Id);

public JsonResult GetUsers()
{
    var ret = (from user in db.Users
               orderby user.UserName
               select new
               {
                   UserName = user.UserName,
                   Pic = pic,
               }).AsEnumerable();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But because user does not exist outside the query you should use `.ToList()` to defer the use of your function. With `.ToList()` after data is loaded, any further operation (such as `select`) is performed using *Linq to Objects*, on the data already in memory. So your query should be like this:

```
public JsonResult GetUsers()
{
    var ret = (from user in db.Users.ToList()
               orderby user.UserName
               select new
               {
                   UserName = user.UserName,
                   Pic = GetFileData(user.Id),
               }).AsEnumerable();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```