# LINQ doesn't accept static function in a predicate: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I know this question looks like a duplicate but it seems like each case has it's own solution and I can't find the right explanation for this Exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   DateReservationOnTheSameWeek(System.DateTime)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

I just want to compare if two dates are on the same iso week of year, here's my code:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public DateTime DateReservation { get; set; }
    // other methods and properties
    public static bool IsOnQuota(Reservation item)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SchedulingToolContext())
        {
            float qteSem = ctx.Reservations.Where(k => k.CltNameAlpha == item.CltNameAlpha 
                    && k.DateReservation.Year == item.DateReservation.Year
                    && item.DateReservationOnTheSameWeek(k.DateReservation) // this causes the exception
                    ).Sum(k => k.Qte);
            var q = ctx.Quotas.Where(k => k.Id == item.IdQuota).FirstOrDefault();
            return q.QteMaxJour >= item.Qte && q.QteMaxSemaine >= qteSem;
        }
    }
    private static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
    {
        DayOfWeek day = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
        if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            time = time.AddDays(3);
        }
        return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }

    private bool DateReservationOnTheSameWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        return GetIso8601WeekOfYear(this.DateReservation) == GetIso8601WeekOfYear(date);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why this predicate fails.
EDIT: I can't calculate the predicate out of the query because, it depends on k that is part of the lambda function.

Comment: I think you should use `.ToList()` to defer the use of your function. Your question is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061637/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-web-mvc-fileresult

Comment: It's failing because Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate that function in to a database call.  Unfortunately I don't see an obvious or easy fix for your code, since the function relies on `k` which is part of the lambda.  Usually this is fixed by precalculating the result outside the query.

Comment: If you want the week of the year, look to `DatePart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using [SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171(v=vs.100).aspx) and [ISO_WEEK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) will help

```
using (var ctx = new SchedulingToolContext())
{
    float qteSem = ctx.Reservations.Where(k => k.CltNameAlpha == item.CltNameAlpha
                        && k.DateReservation.Year == item.DateReservation.Year
                        && SqlFunctions.DatePart("isowk", this.DateReservation) ==  SqlFunction.DatePart("isowk", k.DateReservation) 
                        ).Sum(k => k.Qte);
                var q = ctx.Quotas.Where(k => k.Id == item.IdQuota).FirstOrDefault();
                return q.QteMaxJour >= item.Qte && q.QteMaxSemaine >= qteSem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know that SqlFunctions existed