# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean ToBoolean

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class Like this :

```
public class menu{
public string Permission{get;set;}
}
```

The value Of `Permission` is Encripted . I want all records where `Permission` is `True`. To do this, I use this query :

```
return 
_menuSettings.Where(row => Convert.ToBoolean(Utilities.Encryption.Decrypt(row.Permission,"key"))==true).ToList();
```

but I get this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean ToBoolean(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I searched on google, but I can't solve it .

thanks

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean` couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061637/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-web-mvc-fileresult/34061692#34061692

Comment: Related posts - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259567/465053) & [Entity Framework Specification Pattern Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352764/465053)

Comment: Another related post - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899683/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for cannot be achieved by db query. I'm afraid you are stuck with in memory filtering (hope your don't have too many records) like this

```
return 
_menuSettings.AsEnumerable().Where(...
```

here `AsEnumerable()` will switch the context from `Linq to Entities` to `Linq to Objects`

Answer (score 2):

Not every method is convertible to SQL thats the essence of that message.

In your case you can compare against the string `"true"`.

```
_menuSettings.Where(row => Utilities.Encryption.Decrypt(row.Permission,"key").ToLower()=="true").ToList();
```

Now as mentioned the message means the method is not convertible to SQL. So then by no real surprise get that `Utilities.Encryption.Decrypt` is also not supported.

Then continue with the same concept of taking things that don't work, out of the query.

The quick and dirty way is to realize/project the data (use ToList() or ToIEnumerable() before you filter with the non-supported filter).

Meaning that you take everything out of the table and filter it on your server instead on the DBMS (SQL server).

Like this. (i have split it into more lines for readability)

```
var projection = _menuSettings.ToList();
var result = projection.Where(row => Utilities.Encryption.Decrypt(row.Permission,"key").ToLower()=="true").ToList();
```

A wise choice is to find a good way to limit the projection size before you do heavy work like this.

Comment: And now he'll get `Utilities.Encryption.Decrypt` not supported

Comment: I getting this Error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Decrypt(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
`