# System.NotSupportedException while trying to filter by ID C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using this code as a filter in a datagridview:

```
private void consultarPorCriterio()
    {
        
        var inspec = from ins in entities.Inspeccions
                        where (ins.Ralladuras.StartsWith(txtTextoABuscar.Text) ||
                               ins.Repuesta.StartsWith(txtTextoABuscar.Text)||
                               ins.ID.ToString().StartsWith(txtTextoABuscar.Text)
                              )
                        select ins;
        dgvInspeccion.DataSource = inspec.ToList();
    }
```

It filters if I remove:

> ins.ID.ToString().StartsWith(txtTextoABuscar.Text).

IF I don't remove that part of code I get this error:

> Exception not handled... 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Aditional Info: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Does someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it  couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it, Have a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061692/2946329

Comment: I took this code from my teachers program, in his program he does the same as I'm trying to do, I mean to filter by ID. Why it works for him and not for me?

Comment: What is the underlying data type of ins.ID?

Comment: Is the ID of the table Inspeccion.

Comment: Your problem here is the call to the method `ToString()` that can't be translated into an SQL statement.

Comment: what can I do then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276.aspx) to convert int to String, with slight modification your code may end up like this:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)ins.ID).StartsWith(txtTextoABuscar.Text)
```

Comment: I tried it, it filters, but datagridview shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that your new query is returning data? Because the part where you bind your datagridview seems ok.