# Error while converting nullable datetime to string in LINQ asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

I am developing an asp.net MVC system with a Kendo UI. I have to send a "date" from a filter button in View to the controller and filter the LINQ. I used this code:

```
public ActionResult Grid_ReadLogAdminList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string filterDate)
        {
            DateTime _temp;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(filterDate, out _temp))
                _temp = DateTime.Now;

            return Json(_context.Entities<LogAdmin>().NoTracking().OrderByDescending(l => l.TimeStamp)
                .Where(f => f.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") == _temp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
                .Select(l => new LogAdminInfo
                {
                    Id = l.Id,
                    Message = l.Message,
                    MessageTemplate = l.MessageTemplate,
                    Level = l.Level,
                    TimeStamp = l.TimeStamp,
                    Exception = l.Exception,
                    Properties = l.Properties,
                    LogEvent = l.LogEvent,
                })
                .ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

but it gave me an error with the ".Where". you should know that TimeStamp field is "datetime?" nullable datetime.

I received this Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

how can I fix the Error?

Comment: You need to first check for your date is null or not.

Comment: I tried to do it. .Where(f => (f.TimeStamp != null ? f.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : "") == _temp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")) .... did not work

Comment: Because it couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. See here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061692/2946329

Comment: first select your field and do ToString in the select close, then apply the where. Select clause is in .NET Field where as Where is in SQL field

Comment: Use   `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode= true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }` at your ViewModel Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty indicative LINQ to Entities does not support the ToString method, you should compare your dates using another approach.

Based on your code I assume you are only interested in the date part of the DateTime  for comparison so I suggest you to try [DbFunctions.TruncateTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)):

```
Where(f => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.TimeStamp) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(_temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
.Where(f => f.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") == _temp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

with

```
.Where(f =>  DbFunctions.TruncateTime(f.TimeStamp) == _temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var tempDate = _temp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")    
    Json(_context.Entities<LogAdmin>().NoTracking().OrderByDescending(l => l.TimeStamp)    
.Select(l => new LogAdminInfo
                    {
                        Id = l.Id,
                        Message = l.Message,
                        MessageTemplate = l.MessageTemplate,
                        Level = l.Level,
                        TimeStamp = l.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"),
                        Exception = l.Exception,
                        Properties = l.Properties,
                        LogEvent = l.LogEvent,
                    }).Where(l => l.TimeStamp = tempDate).Select(l)
                    .ToDataSourceResult(request));
```