# LINQ Select formatted values as a LIST

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to fetch a column value and convert it as a list of formatted string value and I tried the below code

```
List<string> _names = (from p in context.RakHolders select 
    string.Format("{0},{1}",  p.Name.Split(',')[0].Trim(), p.Name.Split(',')[1].Trim()))
    .ToList();
```

My intention is to get a list of names with no unwanted space between commas in the column Name

I am getting exception while executing this line as

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in 
>       EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>       'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, 
>       and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I make this work [get a list of formatted column values] with LINQ

Comment: Because it couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. Add `AsEnumerable()` after `RakHolders` might be helpful. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061637/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-web-mvc-fileresult

Comment: Try adding `.AsEnumerable()` after `context.RakHolders`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> _names = (from p in context.RakHolders select p.Name)
    .ToList()
    .Select(name => name.Split(','))
    .Select(nameSplitted => string.Format("{0},{1}",  nameSplitted[0].Trim(), nameSplitted[1].Trim() ))
    .ToList();
```

Explanation: 'string.Format' cannot be translated to SQL so firstly we need to materialise the list with a first 'ToList()' (here we get the list of names, it's much more efficient than materialising full entities). Having the list in the memory you can transform it to the form you require.

Answer (score 1):

EF is trying to execute the expression on the SQL-Server. If you fetch the items first, it shouldn't be a problem:

```
List<string> _names = context.RakHolders
    .Select(r => r.Name)
    .ToList()
    .Select(p => p.Split(','))
    .Select(s => string.Format("{0},{1}", s[0].Trim(), s[1].Trim())
    .ToList();
```