# Search string within a string array in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Queries["SurnameInitial"]))
{
    var initials = Queries["SurnameInitial"].Split(',').ToList();
        filter.And(s => initials.Contains(s.Surname.ToArray()[0].ToString()));
}
```

It throws exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can i match char vs string?

Comment: Because it couldn't be translated to T-SQL, Linq to Entities couldn't recognize it. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061692/2946329

Comment: I understand from Thomas' answer that `s.Surname.ToArray()[0]` is a char. The Linq namespace contains an extension on IEnumerables  [`Contains(char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx); is that usable? Alternatively, could you use `IndexOf(char)` and test for `!= -1`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following `s.Surname.First()` instead:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Queries["SurnameInitial"]))
{
    var initials = Queries["SurnameInitial"].Split(',');
        filter.And(s => initials.Contains(s.Surname.First()));
}
```

This happens because Linq to Entities doesn't know what to do with `char.ToString()`

Since you're dealing with a `List<string>` you can use:

```
filter.And(s => initials.Any(x => x.Contains(s.Surname.First()));
```

Comment: How can i match char and string?

Comment: @s.k.paul what do you mean?

Comment: initials is a List<string> whereas s.Surname.First() returns a char. How can I compare them?

Answer (score 2):

The following code solved my problem-

```
 var initials = Queries["SurnameInitial"].Split(',').ToList();
 filter.And(s => initials.Contains(s.Surname.Substring(0, 1)));
```